# Repository Not Found Error in TypeScript, when I was connecting to MySQL through the typeorm it was encountering the error

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

The server is listening on 3000. My MySQL database is initialized.

```
RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "User" was found. 
  Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

message: 'No repository for "User" was found. Looks like tes.js) 
{his entity is not registered in current "default" connection?'                 
 his entity is not registered in current "default" connection?'}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add some of the severr code

Comment: No answer till date :| :(

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same problem, You might be trying to use method `getRepository` before database connection is established.

I solved this problem by using  inside async function `const connection = await createConnection()` then `await connection.driver.afterConnect().then()` and then stuff like routes.